# How to convert all images to text in a word doc?

Tags: conversion

These images have text in them and I can't find a tool that does this easily, preferably without any installations.

Comment: If you don't want to install anything, you might want to ask this at SU's [sister site for web apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I don't think such a beast exists; you need something like a languge program that types what you speak; or a scanner program that will scan a dog and enter it into your fav text editor with the same format; something that can translate "read" all the images and convert it to text format.  If you don't have very many you can do some manual conversions; or even cut copy paste ect. but some how I don't think this is what you are looking for, sounds like you have lots to do!

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a screenshot of what kind of documents you want to convert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a web based OCR (Optical Character Recognition) service like [FreeOCR](http://www.free-ocr.com/).